# What is the subset of the letters in the word 'numbers'

Tags: recreational-mathematics

What is the subset of the letters in 'numbers'?

I thought it meant to make a word out of the letters in 'numbers' so I tried to make a word out of it, but I couldn't make a word and so I don't understand the task.

Please help me this is my homework. If I don't bring it to school by Friday I'll be put in detention for 5 hours.

Comment: It seems rather strange to give 5 hours detention for getting one math question wrong.  There may be more to this story.  Also, `numbers' is not a set, it is a word.  Hence it has no subsets.  Please ask the precise question you were asked, not a rephrasing.

Comment: @vadim123 I'm guessing the question means the set {n, u, m, b, e, r, s}. Still, you can't find *the* subset of this set as there are 129 of them with the empty set. As vadim123 said, this question seems rephrased.

Comment: @RandomUser shouldn't that be $2^6 = 128$ subsets?  But, still, the point still stands--the use of "the" subset is not appropriate here.

Comment: @anorton You are correct. Typo on my part.

Answer (score 1):

When you say all letters are a-z, you can write the set of all letters as

$$\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z\}$$

The subset of all letters that are in the word "numbers" is

$$\{n,u,m,b,e,r,s\}$$

---

### Side note

There are much more letters:

- [Greek alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet): α, β, γ, ...
- [Russian alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet): а, б, в, г, д, ...
- [Hebrew alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet): א, ב, ג
- ...